# Installing Jupyter in Ubuntu System

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I tried to install Jupyter using the command: `pip install jupyter`

I have Python version 2.7 installed. While trying to install jupyter, I get the following error

```
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ZEAIQG/scandir/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lAQhvB-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ZEAIQG/scandir/
```

Can someone please help me solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Did you install python-dev? `sudo apt-get install python-dev`...

Comment: I also add this problem some time ago. I fix it by installing ipython notebook instead. It works the same. (`pip install ipython`)

Comment: @errata yeah, its installed

Comment: @nuageus tried that as well, im getting

error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scandir.py'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use this command to install the necessary dependcies

**apt-get install build-essential python-dev**